# Cannot override h2 style in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I make three heading texts in a WordPress page and rewrite the CSS if screen width is smaller than 820px. Below is the code I do.

```
<h1 class="block-h1">Heading 1</h1>
<h2 class="block-h2">Heading 2</h2>
<h3 class="block-h3">Heading 3</h3>

@media screen and (max-width: 819px) {
    h1.block-h1 { font-size:1.2em; line-height:12px; top:10%;}
    h2.block-h2 { font-size:1.4em; line-height:14px; top: 50%;}
    h3.block-h3 { font-size:1.8em; line-height:10px; top: 70%;}
}
```

Only the <h1> and <h3> can be rewrote, but the style of <h2> cannot be override, the .post-content h2 is kept. Style is added add the footer of the page.

http://screencloud.net/v/tlTe[image]

Comment: Can you show us more code? What is surrounding the `h` elements?

Comment: What do you mean the code surrounding the h elements? The HTML or CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding the **hierarchy** of how **CSS** is read in precedence could help you in this scenario.

*Disclaimer*, you should avoid these; and just update the code in the actual stylesheet, or make conditionals within; but if you can't consider the below.

**1.)** To override a external `/css.css` stylesheet. This is the easiest to override; you can have styles within the `.html` page referencing (you can put these anywhere and it will override) Eg. within the `<head><style>span { color: red; }</style></head>`

**2.)** If you need to override a on-page style similar to as quoted as within the `</head>` above. You'll need to declare an inline style which takes the ultimate precedence. *Eg*. `<span class="purple" style="color:red;">yooo</span>`

**3.)** If your having issues still.. your css could be inserted via JS or jQuery or even a server side include making it a bit tricker; most of the time you can add a simple `!important` to where your trying to override. *Eg*. `<head><style>span { color: red !important; }</style></head>`

**4.)** If your still having issues; then there is something going on very odd here; in which you should try to debug. But jQuery could override most scenarios pretty good as well (though you really shouldn't have to use such a low level technique for css styles)

But- you can simply do this:

```
$("span").css("color","red");
```

Or.. Remove the previous styles first -- and then *replace*.

```
$("span").removeAttr('style').css("color","purple");
```

and then add the correct one with any of the above methods!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because the theme you are using is forcing embedded styles. This can probably be because there is a theme options somewhere and the developer is using php to force it to the DOM. Embedded Styles override External styles, and in turn, inline styles override Embedded.

You can tell this is happening from the chrome dev tools as it says the source is: `?page_id=54 LINE NUMBER`

You can override them by looking into your themes custom settings, tracking down the code which the developer is pushing to the page, or as user3313126 says, use `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important to force override default style

Example

```
 h2.block-h2 { font-size:1.4em!important; line-height:14px!important; top: 50%;!important}
```

Hope this work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just making your rule for your h2 more specific?

```
#wrapper .post-content h2.block-h2 {}
```

Comment: Yes, I can make rule more specific to make it work, just don't know why both h1 and h2 post on same page but have different result. Don't know what control the code and how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Add **!important** after css code.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.